# ASE isql is frozen after each huge select query

Tags: sybase

I have a stored procedure and it has several insert/update statements. Then it has at last a huge select statement and after the selection of more than 1000 records ASE isql stops working, it just shows "Executing", but nothing else is working, I cannot connect or reconnect again. The same happens when I have a small select query.
Can somebody explain me, why?
I am working on SYBASE 15

Comment: Are you committing your changes before the select?  Could it be waiting for an exclusive lock to free up to continue the select?

Comment: It is working on RApid and DBArtesian without any problem. That is why  I ask this question.I am afraid the problem is with ASE ISQL because somewhere is set up incorrect. Also My SP is unchained. It does not wait until submitting.